# Netty - create Channel wrapper around native FileDescriptor

Tags: netty, file-descriptor

I have native code which I would like to re-write in Java - Netty.

One of the challenges is that the native code makes use of native APIs to open connections to file descriptors received from other processes by `recvmsg()`, tty file descriptors received as command line arguments, from calls to `socketpair()` and more.

I was thinking of implementing a thin native JNI layer to create those file descriptors, then wrap them in Netty's `FileDescriptor`s and create `Channel`s around those FDs.

I guess I still need to figure out some other pieces of such solutions, such as which `EventLoopGroup` should be used for each `Channel` etc. but I first wanted to know whether this has any support in Netty at all.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I think what you want to do can be done... that said you will basically most likely need to write a transport from scratch. I think I would have a look at the Epoll* classes and see how this can be done and go from there.